# How to remove white space, line breaks etc from a string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have a below output and wanted to remove the white space and line breaks.

```
\n', '    var [3:0] apple [1:0];\n', '    int mango;\n', '    float banana [5:0];\n', '    int lichi;\n', '
```

I tried both the below code but its not working. Any comments/corrections ?

```
print str(str(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9[:]]+[\r\n]+', ' ', str(match_group_t[i]))))
print re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])\r?\n"," ", match_group_t[i])
```

Drop in your comments for any correction !

Expected Output is : Only
`var [3:0] apple [1:0], int mango, float banana [5:0], int lichi.` So that I can store type and name separately in an array and use it later. Like

```
variable data in an array: [apple, var, lelem, [3:0], rleme, [1:0]]
```

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: You are not gonna want to use regex for removing whitespace and linebreaks in python. Just do `string.replace(" ", "")` and `string.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want your output to be (e.g., do you want to preserve the space in `var apple`?), but I don't see why a variant of `print(re.sub("\s{2,}", "", s))` wouldn't suffice offhand.

Comment: @truecam:   print match_group_t[i].replace("\n",""). Is not replace the required \n with "".

Comment: This is what I got. It worked for me
`>>> a = "\n asifjdiasd fjj jads \n"`

`>>> a.replace("\n", "")`

`' asifjdiasd fjj jads '`

Comment: Expected output of `var [3:0] apple [1:0], int mango, float banana [5:0], int lichi` is not compatible with "removing whitespace" -- there are obviously spaces in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the expression in `re.sub`:

```
(?:[;\n']|\s{2,})
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[;\n']` Characters `;`  ,  `\n` and `'`.
  - `|` Or
  - `\s{2,}` Whitespace, two or more.
- `)` Close non capturing group.

Python code:

```
import re
mystr = "\n', '    var [3:0] apple [1:0];\n', '    int mango;\n', '    float banana [5:0];\n', '    int lichi;\n', '  "

print(re.sub(r"(?:[;\n']|\s{2,})",r'',mystr)[2:])
```

Prints the desired output:

```
var [3:0] apple [1:0], int mango, float banana [5:0], int lichi,
```

Comment: I tried your tried above, But this is the output I am getting.

Output before applying your approach:    \n', '    var [3:0] apple [1:0];\n', '    int mango;\n', '    float banana;\n', '    int lichi;\n', '  
Output after applying your approach: , var [3:0] apple [1:0]\n, int mango\n, float banana\n, int lichi\n, 

Can you please provide some note on your approach so that I can try to edit and I am slightly new to this reg approach.

Comment: How did you try it? Copy and paste it in and should print what I showed in my answer. I'll add notes for the regex.

Comment: Standalone it works, when I tried using in the bigger program its printing the different output.
Bigger problem is posted in below link for different query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905869/how-to-extract-only-particular-set-of-structs-from-a-file-between-braces-in-pyth

Comment: *Bigger program* do you mean a bigger text file?

Comment: @UnbearabelLightness: Have tried your approach in the bigger code and updated the code.. But output is slightly different in there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905869/how-to-extract-only-particular-set-of-structs-from-a-file-between-braces-in-pyth

Comment: We can only work with the information you give us. This question is solved, my answer prints the desired output. The other one you linked is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the built-in `isspace` instead of regular expressions.

```
newstring = ''.join(ch for ch in oldstring if not ch.isspace())
```